# Lost RAID1 after Ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: raid

Last Friday my computer updated to 16.04, but then failed to come back up. I had a RAID1 setup before with two identical disks. Now when I look at the Marvell RAID settings, it seems that only one of the disks is in the RAID, the other is now shown as a Free Physical disk. Not sure how to recover. Any help would be most appreciated.